# Condition on Sum when using inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables :

```
a
idA User Size 
b
idB status name
```

`User` is a foreign key from `a` to `b`.

This query worked well:

```
SELECT a.User,a.size,b.status,b.name, SUM(a.size) as TotalSize
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.User=b.idB
WHERE a.size> 10
GROUP BY User
ORDER BY TotalSize DESC
```

but when I tried to PUT A condition on the sum it fails:

```
SELECT a.User,a.size,b.status,b.name, SUM(a.size) as TotalSize
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.User=b.idB
WHERE TotalSize > 10  # or WHERE SUM(a.size)  > 10
GROUP BY User
ORDER BY TotalSize DESC
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `having` clause (which goes after the `group by`):

```
HAVING TotalSize > 10  # or HAVING SUM(a.size)  > 10
```

This is the right way to filter the results from an aggregation function.

Comment: thanks it worked I'll accept the answer as soon as I can